# Bulk update within embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When adding entries to the daily key, there are two cases to be handled

a) Addition of a new day -: { "day": 6, "sessions": 300}

b) Updating fields for a specific day, like if sessions were recalculated and changed to 105 for 2nd day

Sample Schema

```
{
    _id: "201010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
    metadata: {
        date: ISODate("2000-10-00T00:00:00Z"),
        site: "site-1",
        page: "/apache_pb.gif" },
    daily: [
        { "day": 1, "sessions": 300, "bounces": 10},
        { "day": 2, "sessions": 100, "bounces": 5},
        { "day": 3, "sessions": 10},
        { "day": 4, "sessions": 100, "bounces": 4}
    ]
}
```

I initially tried this

```
db.monthly.update(
    { "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif", "daily.day": "6" },
    { "$set": { "daily.$.sessions": 300 } },
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

but if the day is not present, I get "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query"

The only way I can see the operations happening are

```
db.monthly.update(
    { "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif", "daily.day": "6" },
    { "$set": { "daily.$.sessions": 300 } }
)
```

and in the response if I get modified is 0, then I do this

```
db.monthly.update(
    { "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif" },
    { "$push": { "daily": {
        "day": "6",
        "sessions": 300
    }}
)
```

This doesn't seem elegant at all. Any idea if we can do this using a single query? (BulkOperations perhaps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your title suggests, the solution to this is to use the [Bulk Operations API](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/), which can be used to send mutiple operations in a single request with a single response:

```js
var bulk = db.monthly.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// Attempt to match and modify
bulk.find({ "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif", "daily.day": 6 }).updateOne({
    "$inc": { "daily.$.sessions": 600 }
});

// Attempt to push where matched and array element does not exist
bulk.find({ "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif", "daily.day": { "$ne": 6 } }).updateOne({
    "$push": { "daily": { "day": 6, "sessions": 600 } }
});

// upsert and only modify on actual creation
bulk.find({ "metadata.page": "/apache_pb.gif" }).upsert().updateOne({
    "$setOnInsert": {
        "_id": "201010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
        "metadata": {
            "date": ISODate("2000-10-00T00:00:00Z"),
            "site": "site-1",
            "page": "/apache_pb.gif" 
        },
        "daily": [
            { "day": 6, "sessions": 600 }
        ]
    }
});

// The only time the server is actually touched.
bulk.execute();
```

So while there are three operations to handle all cases in the batch, there is only every one request made to the server and one response. Also note that it is only possible for **one** of the set of operations to actually modify or create some data.

The basic case is to match and modify where the required elements exist. If the conditions are met, then the array element is updated. "Incremented", in this example since there was earlier mention of pre-aggregated data, and usually incrementing the value already present makes sense in this case.

The following step is to test where the array member does not exist, and then of course `$push` the new element into the array.

Finally there is the "upsert" condition, which is purposefully absent from the previous statements. This deliberately does not look at the array elements, but rather just a unique property of the document. Only then is it safe to consider an "upsert" when that query condition is not met, as adding an array element in the check could create a new document when the intent was adding to an array.

The [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) modifier here makes sure that no change is made to any document that is actually found, and the only operations that occur is when an "upsert" actually happens.

So controlling additions to an array and cosidering "upsert" behaviour requires these basic steps. However the usage of "Bulk Operations" makes this a single request/response to the server as well as the general logic ensuring that only one operation will ever have any effect.

It's very efficient and removes the overhead of needing to perform each of these operations while communicating back and forth with the server in request and response until one of the operations succeeds.

One query/update is not possible for this control. But one request, is possible and this is what it does.